# python nsolve/solve triple of equations

Tags: python, sympy

I keep getting errors when I tried to solve a system of three equations using the following code in python3:

---

```
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol, solve, nsolve

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
z = Symbol('z')

eq1 = x - y + 3
eq2 = x + y
eq3 = z - y

print(nsolve( (eq1, eq2, eq3), (x,y,z), (-50,50)))
```

---

Here is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py", line
>   928, in findroot
>      fx = f(*x0)
>   TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument:
>   '_Dummy_15'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "", line 12, in    File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.py", line 2498,
>   in nsolve
>      x = findroot(f, x0, J=J, **kwargs)
>     File
>   "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py", line
>   931, in findroot
>      fx = f(x0[0])
>   TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments:
>   '_Dummy_14' and '_Dummy_15'

---

The strange thing is, the error message goes away if I only solve the first two equation --- by changing the last line of the code to

```
print(nsolve( (eq1, eq2), (x,y), (-50,50)))
```

output:

```
exec(open('bug444.py').read())
[-1.5]
[ 1.5]
```

I'm baffled; your help is most appreciated!

A few pieces of additional info:

- I'm using python3.4.0 + sympy 0.7.6-3 on ubuntu 14.04.  I got the same error in python2
- I could solve this system using

  solve( [eq1,eq2,eq3], [x,y,z] )

but this system is just a toy example; in the actual applications the system is non-linear and I need higher precision, and I don't see how to adjust the precision for solve, whereas for nsolve I could use `nsolve(... , prec=100)`

THANKS!

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/12052

Comment: By the way, you should know that setting the precision in `nsolve` requires the git version of SymPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your print statement, you are missing your guess for `z`:

```
print(nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (x, y, z), (-50, 50)))
```

Try this (in most cases, using `1` for all the guesses is fine):

```
print(nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (x, y, z), (1, 1, 1)))
```

**Output:**

```
[-1.5]
[ 1.5]
[ 1.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can discard the initial guesses/dummies if you use [`linsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.linsolve):

```
>>> from sympy import linsolve
>>> print(linsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), x,y,z))
{(-3/2, 3/2, 3/2)}
```

And then you can use [`nonlinsolve`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve) for your non linear problem set.

Comment: `nonlinsolve` will only work if the system has a closed-form solution, which is often (usually) not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is number of variables should be equal to the number of guess vectors,

`print(nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3), (x,y,z), (-50,50,50)))`

If you're using a numerical solver on a multidimensional problem, it wants to start from somewhere and follow a gradient to the solution.
the guess vector is where you start.
if there are multiple local minima / maxima in the space, different guess vectors can lead to diffierent outputs.
Or an unfortunate guess vector may not converge at all.
For a one-dimensional problem the guess vector is just x0.
For most functions you can write down easily, almost any vector will converge to the one global solutions.

so (1,1,1) guess vectors here is as good as (-50,50,50)
Just don't leave a null space for the sake of program

Answer (score 0):

your code should be:

```
nsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x,y,z], [1,1,1])
```

your code was:

```
nsolve([eq1, eq2, eq3], [x,y,z], [1,1])
```

you were mising one guess value in the last argument.

point is: if you are solving for `n` unknown terms you provide a guess for each unknown term (`n` guesses in the last argument)